# Uncrustify: Trim linebreaks before braces

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uncrustify

What is the right config for uncrustify so that it removes empty lines before curly braces so that:

```
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // foo
    }
    [bar tend];

}
```

becomes:

```
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // foo
    }
    [bar tend];
}
```

I scourged the docs but couldn't find the right setting, maybe it has an unusual name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The following will take care of spurious blank lines.

```
eat_blanks_after_open_brace   = TRUE
eat_blanks_before_close_brace = TRUE
nl_max = 2
```